# Why can I not bevel?

Tags: bevel

I'm new to 3d modeling and I bought this book by Arijan Belec and one of his steps in this book is to bevel the edge of part of the model but every time I apply the bevel, I get no reaction.[image]

Comment: bevel depends on your geometry. Maybe you share your object via blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: As I can see by the slightly thicker than usual black lines you have a lot of overlapping geometry there which is most probably the issue. Is it taught to be modeled like that in the book?

Comment: As Gordon says, the topology is probably bad, maybe try a M > Merge by Distance to see if it fixes the problem